# Apache storm and RabbitMQ Spout on Clojure

Tags: clojure, rabbitmq, apache-storm, amqp

I was previously working with Kafka as my data source and found it very powerful but had a rather steep learning curve managed to get it partially working but had a few hitches here and there and don't feel comfortable maintaining it in production.

So decided to switch over to Rabbitmq since I am more familiar with it however I have run into a slight problem.

I am unable to find a Clojure Library for Apache Storm Spouting from Rabbitmq. Should I extend BaseRichSpout or can someone point me to a useful library.

Answer (score 0):

There was no clear cut library to assist with this so I extended the 
"BaseRichSpout" in java code, compiled to a jar file and imported it to clojure code.

There was quite a bit of diddling around because my Storm cluster was running backtype version i.e. older version of storm.

However [this](https://github.com/ppat/storm-rabbitmq) was the sample code I used.